# Div under a div

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I'm kind of stuck on what seems to be something trivial but I just can’t get my head round it.

Basically I have the address div and then the menu..... Which should go under the address div but it’s seems to be floating next to the address div.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `clear` directive to your menu:

```
#contact-menu {
    clear: both;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:90px;
}
```

That tells the browser that there are no floating elements allowed on either side of the contact menu.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both` to `#contact-menu`.

Comment: Oh god, sure, dunno why i saw there a class.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, `<br />` would probably do the trick. But if you're like me, you think that `<br />` is for text only. `#address{display: block;}#contact-menu{display: block;}` should do the trick, as block elements force a line break before and after the element. Didn't bother editing the CSS; hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, `<br />` doesn't help at all, it just pushes the element one row downwards. That is by the height of one _text_ row. If the preceding element is higher than that, it still causes trouble. You second solution also doesn't work well if one of the elements is floating (which is the case here).

Comment: Thank you. I must say, positioning in CSS is not one of my strengths (yet...). I'll be sure to remember this.